# Объясните, пожалуйста, алгоритм

Tags: python, алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Алгоритм я нагуглил, но не понял. Почему именно кратное деление на стороны?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Comment: А ломать обязательно по границе долек? (в условии это не указано). Если это не так, то достаточно `if (k <= a * b)`

Comment: @Komdosh, Всё, понял, спасибо! Ваше объяснение достойно быть ответом)

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, Как пожелаете :)

Comment: Не помещайте текст/код  в виде картинки в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делим только один раз, значит логично предположить, что отломанная часть должна быть кратна стороне, чтобы можно было отломить полоску с k дольками. Попробуйте нарисовать, наверное, станет понятнее.